# What master's degree is recommended to study at a university for establishing a start-up?

Tags: masters, economics, business-school, management

I studied for 3 years computer science at a relatively good university, and at the same time I have several years of experience with broad and deep knowledge in many fields on the subject. I am a creative person and I am interested in expressing my Innovative ideas by setting up a start-up from scratch which will bring a technological solution to many companies in high-tech.

I wanted to ask in general what it is recommended to study for a master's degree so that I can bring the product that I can build independently through my knowledge of computer science and experience to a successful start-up company?

Comment: Majoring in Entrepreneurship can be a suggestions.

Comment: Talk with someone who has been involved in a start-up, one akin to what you have in mind, before committing yourself to a new degree. He or she will have invaluable information for you.

Comment: https://workplace.stackexchange.com/q/171411/2952

Answer (score 2):

Given that a start up is a business and your education is elsewhere, it would probably do you well to get some specific knowledge of business and the regulations that typically govern business. An MBA might be appropriate if it is focused on entrepreneurship. Economics is probably not what you want, being a more theoretical course of study. Marketing might be an alternative. But it would depend on the particulars.

You can hire business experience, of course, once you have some revenue or can talk people in to working for nearly nothing, but lack of knowledge yourself might mean you need to trust them more than is wise.

Answer (score 0):

Master degrees vary from each university, so in general I would recommend Management. Management is a good basis for organizing and leading a company. Once you know that, you can employ other people to do the more specific jobs, like accounting/finance, marketing, etc.
In some